# Find basis and dimension of $V,W,V\cap W,V+W$ where $V=\{p\in\mathbb{R_4}(x):p'(0) = p(1)=p(0)=p(-1)\},W=\{p\in\mathbb{R_4}(x):p(1)=0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find basis and dimension of $V,W,V\cap W,V+W$ where $V=\{p\in\mathbb{R_4}(x):p'(0) =p(1)=p(0)=p(-1)\},W=\{p\in\mathbb{R_4}(x):p(1)=0\}$

Could someone give a hint how to get general representation of a vector in $V$ and $W$?

$\mathbb{R}_4(x)$ is the set of polynomials $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$.

Comment: what do you mean with $p'(0) \wedge p(1) = ..$ ? Do you mean $p'(0)=p(1)=...$?

Comment: @Adam Yes, it is $p^{'}(0)=...=p(-1)$.

Comment: TeX note: the prime has a built-in superscript, so just type "p prime" ($p'$), not "p carat prime" ($p^{'}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(x)= a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 +a_3 x^3$ be a polynomial of degree 3.

The polynomial $p$ is in $W$ if and only if $a_0 + a_1 +a_2+a_3 = 0$.
Thus it easy to see that the polynomials $p_1(x) = 1-x, \, p_2(x) = x-x^2 , \, p_3(x) = x^2 -x^3$ are in $W$, linearly independent, and they must be a basis because $\mathbb{R}_4 \neq W$. Thus $dim W =3$.

A little computation shows, the polynomial $p$ is in $V$ if and only if $a_1 = a_0 = - a_3$. Thus one possible basis is $q_1(x)=1+x-x^3, \, q_2(x)=x^2$. Thus $dim V =2$.

The polynomial $p$ is in $V \cap W$ if and only if $a_1 = a_0 = - a_3$ and $a_0 + a_2 = 1$ thus $q_2 \in V \cap W$ and it must be a basis because  $V \cap W \neq V$. Thus, $dim V \cap W = 1$.

For finite vector spaces $V$ and $W$, it is known that
$$ dim (V+W) = dimV + dim W - dim V\cap W, $$ this might help you.